# PubsubToBQ tableCreation before insert

Tags: java, google-cloud-dataflow, apache-beam, google-cloud-pubsub, apache-beam-io

I'm trying to make a life Bigquery table creation before the inserting process itself. Here is the code of PTransform that I'm using -> [Link](https://gist.github.com/matthieucham/85459eff5fdea8d115be520e2dd5ccc1)

This transform I would like to apply on Pubsub messages that would be inserted in BQ table later.

- Phase 1. Getting pubsub messages:

  ```
       PCollection<PubsubMessage> messages =
           pipeline.apply(
                   "ReadPubSubSubscription",
                   PubsubIO.readMessagesWithAttributes()
                           .fromSubscription(options.getInputSubscription()));
  ```
- Phase 2. Convert all pubsub messages to TableRow:

  ```
        PCollectionTuple convertedTableRows =
                messages
                    .apply("ConvertMessageToTableRow", new PubsubMessageToTableRow(options));
  ```
- Phase 3. Here is the problem, I need to check if table exist and upload the result to BQ:

  ```
    ###here is the schema for our BQ table
    public static final Schema schema1 =
        Schema.of(
                Field.of("name", StandardSQLTypeName.STRING),
                Field.of("post_abbr", StandardSQLTypeName.STRING));

    ### here is the method that we using to extract table name from pubsub attributes
    static class PubSubAttributeExtractor implements SerializableFunction<ValueInSingleWindow<TableRow>, String> {

    private final String attribute;

    public PubSubAttributeExtractor(String attribute) {
        this.attribute = attribute;
    }

    @Override
    public String apply(ValueInSingleWindow<TableRow> input) {
        TableRow row = input.getValue();
        String tableName = (String) row.get("name");
        return "my-project:myDS.pubsub_" + tableName;
    }
    }
    ### here is the part that doesn't work 
    WriteResult writeResult = convertedTableRows.get(TRANSFORM_OUT)                
            .apply(new BigQueryAutoCreateTable(
                      new PubSubAttributeExtractor("event_name"),schema1));
            .apply(
                            "WriteSuccessfulRecords",
                            BigQueryIO.writeTableRows()
                                    .withoutValidation()
                                    .withCreateDisposition(CreateDisposition.CREATE_NEVER)
                                    .withWriteDisposition(WriteDisposition.WRITE_APPEND)
                                    .withExtendedErrorInfo()
                                    .withMethod(BigQueryIO.Write.Method.STREAMING_INSERTS)
                                    .withFailedInsertRetryPolicy(InsertRetryPolicy.retryTransientErrors())
                                    .to(new ProbPartitionDestinations(options.getOutputTableSpec())
                                    )
                    );
  ```

Error logs:
*cannot find symbol
symbol:   method apply(java.lang.String,org.apache.beam.sdk.io.gcp.bigquery.BigQueryIO.Write<com.google.api.services.bigquery.model.TableRow>)
location: interface org.apache.beam.sdk.values.POutput*

Comment: Why do you need to test if the table exists? CREATE_IF_NEEDED isn't the answer to your use case? Else, explain more your requirements

Comment: @guillaumeblaquiere, I need it because of this [BEAM-3772](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/BEAM-3772?page=com.atlassian.jira.plugin.system.issuetabpanels%3Acomment-tabpanel&focusedCommentId=17264008#comment-17264008) issue that they couldn't fix for the last year. If I used _CREATE_IF_NEEDED_ it will create tables for the first few messages and after that start to send error message -> TABLE NOT FOUND

Comment: Understood, I wasn't aware of this issue!! What is your beam version? I will test something and let you know

Comment: I'm using beam 2.25

Comment: Do you need a different table according to the PubSub attribute?